# mysql fail to start after restarting mysql server on CWP

Tags: linux, mysql, webserver, vps

I restarted the MySQL server by pressing the "restart" button inside CWP web panel and the server stopped working and gave me this error.

```
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Too many levels of symbolic links in 
/usr/local/cwpsrv/htdocs/resources/admin/include/functions.php on line 0

Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Too many levels of symbolic links in 
/usr/local/cwpsrv/htdocs/resources/admin/include/functions.php on line 0

Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Too many levels of symbolic links in 
/usr/local/cwpsrv/htdocs/admin/admin/index.php on line 0

Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Too many levels of symbolic links in 
/usr/local/cwpsrv/htdocs/admin/admin/index.php on line 0


DISK FULL: Can't start MySQL!


Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in 
/usr/local/cwpsrv/htdocs/admin/admin/index.php on line 0
Could not connect:
```

Please help.

Comment: "DISK FULL: Can't start MySQL!" what is not clear?

Comment: WHat can i do to resolve the issue?

Comment: access your server directly using ssh (not a panel) and investigate where space is taken in order to free what can be freed (eg: some logs)